# R - Converting list of separating strings into a string

Tags: r

So I am trying to remove the stopwords of a vector of 318591 strings.

By doing this I am using this

```
X<-lapply(articles_and_id[,2], function(x) {
   t <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
   t[t %nin% stopWords]
```

Where my strings get split, and end up in a list looking like this:

```
>X[[1]]
[[1]]
 [1] "new"           "relictual"     "highly"        "troglomorphic" "species"          "tomoceridae"   "collembola"   
 [8] "deep"          "croatian"      "cave"
```

So I want to put it back into a dataframe transforming it into the following form:

```
1                      new, relictual, highly, troglomorphic, species, tomoceridae, collembola, deep, croatian, cave
```

for which I am using:

```
  articles_and_id[,2] <- lapply(X,toString)
```

But it is just endless!!!!

Any suggestions on how to improve this? If I stop the run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
 articles_and_id[,2] <- sapply(X,paste, collapse=" ")
```